# How can I capture videos and audio in Java?

Tags: java, audio, video

How can I capture *video* and *audio* - what Java classes support this? 
I want to be able to save video and audio that is already captured in memory - any samples in Java for video and audio capturing would be helpful.

I read about how play audio from hard disk:

[here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077521/learn-java/java-tip-24--how-to-play-audio-in-applications.html)

any example or topics to read about capure video and camera

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at the Java Media Framework (JMF).

Reference & Documentation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-140239.html

Examples: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/content/jmf-sample-code.zip